# Tourney RD upgrade

Tags: derailleur-rear

I have a Shimano Tourney rear derailleur that has an extension claw (hanger).  I would like to replace it with a Deore M591.  Do I need to install an adapter to make up the length of the claw?  Someone told me I needed a shift index hanger plate.  Does that sound correct?

Answer (score 2):

If your frame requires a claw (i.e. doesn't have a derailleur hanger), you need to get the claw. Sunrace among others make them, and your local bike shop should have them laying around for about 5 dollars.

According to Jenson USA, the part from Sunrace is called a Index Hanger Plate.